# how to save data locally in HTML5 web page so that we do not need to fetch from server again and again?

Tags: javascript, html, jsonp, local-storage, web-sql

I want to make an app through HTML5 through which user can visit and store data for offline, could any one give me references for that?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp, http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use HTML 5 local storage.
[Example](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/)

Comment: Thanks Now its easy to understand.